# liboauth not being linked correctly

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, linker-errors

I am trying to add the liboauth.dylib to my xcode project (c++). I have configured and made the library, which is now sitting in my `/usr/local/lib` which now has:

```
 liboauth.0.dylib
 liboauth.dylib <- a link to liboauth.0.dylib
 liboauth.li
 liboauth.a
```

with the header in `usr/local/include`. Seems fine.

I have included this in my xcode by adding the path `/usr/local/lib/liboauth.dylib` to the `Other Linker Flags` section, and `usr/local/include/` to the `Header Search Paths`.

I have also included the same in the `Library Search Paths`.

This builds fine on my system. However if I take the resulting .app to another (osx) computer it gives the error the `/usr/local/liboauth.0.dylib` (I get this by opening the .app and running the unix executable).

Shouldn't the linker have included the liboauth dylib when built? And then it shouldn't be a problem when going to a different computer?

If the answer is no, then how would I go about included the liboauth.dylib into the .app, so it can run on any computer (running osx)?

Here is the specific error:

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liboauth.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/scratch/gameTest.app/Contents/MacOS/gameTest
Reason: image not found
```

**Edit:** I have found the problem! Using the otool -l command on the liboauth.0.dylib I found this:

```
Load command 3
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/local/lib/liboauth.0.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Thu Jan  1 12:00:01 1970
      current version 9.1.0
compatibility version 9.0.0
```

Can someone help me to figure out how to change this? I think it has something to do with the install_name_tool but I do not know how to go about it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are both system the same? 32-bit/64-bit, Snow Leopard vs. Leopard.

I can see how the libraries would be different and that error could be produced if that was the case.

If they are the same, it is possible that you are setting the linker flags in your project settings and it is being overridden by your target settings.

Comment: Yes, both are Snow Leopard.

Just to confirm only my os has liboauth installed. The other computer does not. I am expecting my app to include liboauth.dylib inside of, and read from it. As opposed to trying to read from /usr/local/

Comment: If they are the same, it is possible that you are setting the linker flags in your project settings and it is being overridden by your target settings.

Comment: Hmm, nope, I just double checked this and the are identical in both cases. Good suggestion though.

I have been trying to do this, but still get the same error:
cp -f /usr/local/lib/liboauth.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/liboauth.dylib"; install_name_tool -change ./liboauth.dylib @executable_path/liboauth.dylib "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/$PRODUCT_NAME";

Does this seem right?

Comment: Hey I found a work around here.

I include 'liboauth.dylib' in my .app and then I use 'install_name_tool' with the terminal to change where it was looking for other dylibs etc.

This entails also including libcrypto, libiconv, libidn, libintl, libssl, and libz (and changing all there things is well).

Is this bad, am I breaking rules / doing it wrong?